# How do I Code Global Operations in a Node.js/Express App?

Tags: node.js, express, coldfusion

I'm converting some ColdFusion templates to Node.js/Express. Is there equivalent architecture to the ColdFusion Application.cfm/cfc, where every request causes this template to be executed? I'm having to perform global operations (session mgmt, db connections, etc.) in every route by require()ing each module. That doesn't seem like a good strategy. Is there another way? Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you want Express middleware.  That's where you install things you want to operate on lots of requests (checking authorization is the classic example).

Comment: I believe you are looking for `app.use()` to add middleware [docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.use)

Comment: @MSallam yes, that's it. Thanks. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `app.use` :

```
app.use(req, res, next) {
  // code to run on every request here

  next()
}
```

[Docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.use)